# Finding Squares in an array

Tags: vb.net, arrays, algorithm

I have an 2 dimensional array that is full of 1s and 0s such as

```
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0
    0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
    0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
    0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
    0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

You can see there is a square in th array.
I am trying to make a function that will make a rectangle or list of rectangles based on the square.
So the example would return a rectangle like

```
rect.x = 2
rect.y = 1
rect.width = 7
rect.height = 5
```

This is the code i have now but it just doe not return anything

```
Dim rects As New List(Of Rectangle)
    For imgWidth As Integer = 0 To bow.GetUpperBound(0)
        For imgHeight As Integer = 0 To bow.GetUpperBound(1)
            If bow(imgWidth, imgHeight) = 1 Then

                If bow(imgWidth + 1, imgHeight) = 1 And 
                   bow(imgWidth + 2, imgHeight) = 1 And 
                   bow(imgWidth, imgHeight + 1) = 1 And 
                   bow(imgWidth, imgHeight + 2) = 1 Then

                    Dim r As New Rectangle

                    With r
                        .X = imgWidth
                        .Y = imgHeight
                    End With

                    For rectWidth As Integer = imgWidth To bow.GetUpperBound(0)
                        If bow(rectWidth, imgHeight) = 0 Then
                            r.Width = bow(rectWidth - 1, imgHeight)
                        End If
                    Next

                    For rectHeight As Integer = imgHeight To bow.GetUpperBound(1)
                        If bow(imgWidth, rectHeight) = 0 Then
                            r.Height = bow(rectHeight - 1, imgHeight)
                        End If
                    Next

                    rects.Add(r)
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Next
```

Also the array must be able to have more than one square.

Comment: Can you give more details of your problem beyond "it just doe not return anything"? What have you tried?

Comment: When i tried adding break points, but the loops that find the width and height always return 0

Comment: @giodamelio: is this homework? If not, what is it for and why?

Comment: What if the two dimensional array (7x9) is full ones?  Should it return a list of the 756 possible rectangles?

Comment: @JoshD No it is not home work for some reason it was tagged that automatically. The array is read from a file that was created by a different program that originally made the file from a drag and drop interface for putting squares on a canvas.

Comment: @Sheldon L. Coope Yes it should

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I would do it:

```
def rectangles(grid):
  rows = len(grid)
  cols = len(grid[0])

  hor_ones = [[0]] * rows
  for r in range(rows):
    for c in range(cols):
      hor_ones[r].append(hor_ones[r][c] + grid[r][c])

  ver_ones = [[0]] * cols
  for c in range(cols):
    for r in range(rows):
      ver_ones[c].append(ver_ones[c][r] + grid[r][c])

  ret = []
  for r1 in range(rows):
    for c1 in range(cols):
      for r2 in range(r1+1, rows):
        for c2 in range(c1+1, cols):
          if all_ones(hor_ones[r1], c1, c2) and all_ones(hor_ones[r2], c1, c2) and all_ones(ver_ones[c1], r1, r2) and all_ones(ver_ones[c2], r1, r2):
            ret.append((r1, c2, r2, c2))
  return ret

def all_ones(ones, x, y):
  return ones[y+1] - ones[x] == y - x + 1
```

Note that:

- `hor_ones[r][c]` is the number of
  ones in row r in the first c columns.
- `ver_ones[c][r]` is the number of
  ones in column c in the first r rows.

Therefore, the number of ones in row `r` and between columns `c1` and `c2` (inclusive) is:

`hor_ones[r][c2+1] - hor_ones[r][c1]`

**EDIT**

Here's my solution in Java, maybe it is easier for you to understand and implement in VB.NET:

```
public static List<Rectangle> findRectangles(int[][] grid) {
    int rows = grid.length;
    int cols = grid[0].length;

    int[][] horOnes = new int[rows][cols+1];
    for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++)
        for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++)
            horOnes[r][c+1] = horOnes[r][c] + grid[r][c];

    int[][] verOnes = new int[cols][rows+1];
    for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++)
        for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++)
            verOnes[c][r+1] = verOnes[c][r] + grid[r][c];

    List<Rectangle> ret = new ArrayList<Rectangle>();
    for (int r1 = 0; r1 < rows; r1++)
        for (int c1 = 0; c1 < cols; c1++)
            for (int r2 = r1+1; r2 < rows; r2++)
                for (int c2 = c1+1; c2 < cols; c2++)
                    if (allOnes(horOnes[r1], c1, c2) && allOnes(horOnes[r2], c1, c2) && allOnes(verOnes[c1], r1, r2) && allOnes(verOnes[c2], r1, r2))
                        ret.add(new Rectangle(r1, c1, r2, c2));
    return ret;
}

private static boolean allOnes(int[] ones, int x, int y) {
    return ones[y+1] - ones[x] == y - x + 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much but can anyone translate that to vb.net.

Comment: I really have no clue what to do with it.

Comment: @giodmaelio It's python which is a much better language to learn with than VB. to quote [Dijkstra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edsger_Wybe_Dijkstra), "...the teaching of BASIC should be rated as a criminal offence: it mutilates the mind beyond recovery." You'll note that the person that solved your problem is not a VB programmer.

Comment: @Sheldon L. Cooper - Great work! Unfortunately, the constructor for a Rectangle takes width and height - not right and bottom, so you need to fix your instantiation. Additionally, your horOnes and verOnes do not reset to zero - see my answer for the fix.

Comment: @Nescio: "Rectangle" is a class I defined but omitted in my response for brevity.  In Java the arrays of `int` get initialized with zeroes.  I tested my code with a couple of cases and it worked.

Comment: @Sheldon L. Cooper - Ok, I assumed you were using the standard Java Rectangle. Regardless, I believe if you print out the results of your verOnes, or horOnes, you'll see that it extends incorrectly to the right and bottom, thereby creating additional rectangles.

Comment: @Nescio: Could you provide an small input grid that will make my code fail?

Comment: @Sheldon L. Cooper Sure - see my answer

Comment: @Sheldon L. Cooper Basically, you only want to add one, if the grid contains 1, otherwise the count should reset to zero.

Comment: @Nescio: My program works with your case. It outputs: [(0,0,8,9), (2,2,6,7)].

Comment: @Nescio: You seem to be confusing the definition of `hor_ones` and `ver_ones`.  You don't have to reset the count to zero.  Please re-read my definition.

Comment: @Sheldon L. Cooper - You are correct, sorry for my confusion.

Comment: I am having trouble translating the Java to vb.net. In the last round of loops where the if statement is you use horOnes as a 1d array when it is really a 2d array.

Comment: @giodamelio: You can change it to: `if (allOnes(horOnes, r1, c1, c2) && allOnes(horOnes, r2, c1, c2) && allOnes(verOnes, c1, r1, r2) && allOnes(verOnes, c2, r1, r2))`.  Then the function would be: `boolean allOnes(int[][] ones, int k, int x, int y) { return ones[k][y+1] - ones[k][x] == y - x + 1; }`

Comment: @AaronMcSmooth If you think Basic is so bad, what language do you suggest i learn?